# I failed to get data from js through ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I failed to get data from below js through ajax to php, is there someone who can help me to solve his problem?

```js
// Testing Graph API after login.
// See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {

  console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information...');

  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '' + response.name + '!'; 
            
    //ajax used to get the name from response.name to php
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'result.php',
      data: { name: response.name },
      success: function (msg) {
        /* do something */
      }   
    });

  });

}
```

And in php file I'm getting data like below when I click submit button

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['name'];
echo"$name";
?>
```

I failed and I used `include("result.php");`
But no data displayed

Actually response.name have name value but I failed to get it in php variable

Please anyone can help me

Comment: your php file shoud ask for `$_POST[]` not `$_GET[]`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Why are you even sending this value to PHP? It seems to me that all you want to do is display the name that you got from the API.

Comment: Yes I want to get the profile username of Facebook and put it in php variable in order to insert it in database

Comment: Does `console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);` show the name?

Comment: Yes, console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name); shows the name exactly

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a frontend problem (where the request is not built properly), or a backend problem (where the request is not handled properly by the PHP script)?

Comment: As it seems the name is displayed in <DIV> like this <div id="status">
</div>, and then facebook js at the bottom like this <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>. How can I pass <DV> value in input text or in php variable if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are using post request so you should use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` to get the values from ajax and proceed with the further coding

```
<?php
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 echo"$name";
?>
```

Comment: I used $_POST or $_REQUEST but I'm still getting empty in $name, is there any other approach I can use to get the value from response.name to php variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change your js file to this:

```js
function testAPI() {                     
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        '' + response.name + '!';
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'result.php',
        data: {name: response.name },
        success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }   
        });
    });
}
```

And change your php file to this:

```php
<?php
 print_r($_POST);
?>
```

and then go to the console and search for the name variable, if you can find the `name` variable then all things is fine.

Comment: I edited but i'm getting Array ( [message] => this is text box value [send] => Post ) I want to get the response.name value (facebook profile username)

Comment: If I don't enter something in textbox it returns Array ( )

Comment: just change this `data: {name: response.name },` to this `data: {name: "alex" },` and then try and tell the result

Comment: I'm still getting Array ( )

Comment: is the js script and the php file in the same directory? are you sure that you are editing `result.php`?

Comment: Yes, js script is in the same directory with php, I edited result.php where it has <?php
 print_r($_POST);
?> but I still get Array ( )

Comment: I passed div value in variable like $variable = "<div id='status'></div>";
echo"$variable"; it is displaying value, but when I pass variable value in textbox like this echo"<input type=\"text\" name=\"FBUname\" value=\"$variable\">"; I get something like <div= in textbox I don't get real value. the $variable does not allow to be inserted in database. please anyone can help me